# Insurance situation for unpaid babysitter

Tags: united-states, california, insurance

A friend of ours will be looking after our infant daughter for a few days. This will happen at her home with her family. She will do this without charge and we are also in no business relation to each other.

Which insurance would protect the child during this time? My home insurance, my friends insurance or neither? In case of neither are there insurances for such occasion and if yes what are they called?

I googled but couldn't any information about unpaid babysitter.

Comment: Protect the child *from what*?

Comment: @feetwet. With protect I mean would the medical bills be couvered in case of an accident. Not necessarily property damage produced by my toddler.

Answer (score 1):

In general, there are a range of insurances that may or may not apply to your child irrespective of if they are being cared for by you or another person. These include health insurance, life insurance, total & permanent disablement insurance etc. *You* are responsible for taking out this insurance if you want it.

Absent such insurance and absent a contract, the sitter would only be liable if she was negligent: the appropriate policy is a public liability policy. I will bet London to a brick she doesn't have one which leaves her personally liable to the limit of her assets (i.e. until she goes bankrupt).

If an injury was caused by negligence of the property owner, then the public liability clauses of the house insurance would be triggered.

If your child is injured in the absence of negligence then you must bear the costs.

Comment: Thank you for your thorough answer. I'm mainly interested in medical bills for my child. I do not think that she will be negligent, as otherwise she woudn't watch our child, however accidents do happen so I want to have my bases covered. My child has medical insurance, does this mean her bills would be covered by my medical in a case where she for example broke a leg while with the other family?

Comment: @parent123: I'm not a US resident, so ask your insurance broker, but I am pretty sure that your daughter's medical insurance will cover your daughter whoever is looking after her.